# Как работать с файлами на удаленном компьютере

Tags: windows, bat

Есть папка с файлами на удаленном компьютере. И есть скрипт который обрабатывает эти файлы.
Делаю так

```
net use x: \\ip address\Folder
```

Все вижу диск x стал доступен в консоли.

Теперь запускаю скрипт:

```
myScript.bat x:\*.tif
```

Но получаю ошибку

```
x:\*.tif does not exist in file system
```

В консоли могу обратится к файлам с диска х.  Кроме того с локальными файлами скрипт так же прекрасно работает. Да и вообще не сомневаюсь я в работоспособности библиотеки gdal.
Есть ли какие-то особенности с обращением к файлам на удаленном компьютере по маске?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сообщение

> x:\*.tif does not exist in file system

не системное. Т.е. его выдает Ваш скрипт `myScript.bat` по какому поводу он это делает - нам отсюда не видно. Скорее всего таких файлов просто нет в каталоге `x:\`

> Есть ли какие-то особенности с обращением к файлам на удаленном компьютере по маске?

Никаких. Вы сами можете в этом убедиться, выполнив любую системную команду. Например

```
dir x:\*.tif
```

или

```
dir x:\*.*
```

Comment: dir x:\*.tif `выдает The system cannot write to the specified device` Значит ли это что нет каких-то прав на папку?

Comment: @МаксКливер Данное сообщение говорит о том, что имена файлов содержат символы, которые невозможно вывести на консоль в текущей кодировке. Перенаправьте вывод в файл `dir x:\*.tif > C:\filest.txt`

Comment: все понял, свою ошибку. Действительно все дело в кодировке. Спасибо.